# Weird behavior of RichTextBox control

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I'm facing a weird behavior of the `RichTextBox` control:

If have some lines of text displayed in my control (The lines of text are irrelevant to this question i think).

If I select the lines and press backspace or delete nothing happens, whereas when I select the empty line above or underneath my lines of text and press backspace or delete the lines get deleted.

I inspected the `Rtf` property of the `RichTextBox` and noticed a `\v` is getting moved:

This is the `Rtf` when it does get removed:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1031\f0\fs17\par
\v SectionHeader-PowerMatrixConfiguration:\b\v0 Power MatrixConfiguration:\b0\par
blabla
```

and this is the `Rtf`when it doesn't get removed:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1031\v\f0\fs17 SectionHeader-PowerMatrixConfiguration:\b\v0 Power Matrix Configuration:\b0\par
blabla
```

As you can see the first `\v` is moved and a `\par` is missing. Can anybody explain to me why is that and what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: here is my complete `Rtf`. With this I can replicate the problem 100% of the time.

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1031\f0\fs17\par
\v SectionHeader-PowerMatrixConfiguration:\b\v0 Power Matrix Configuration:\b0\line  On OPTOLYZER(01), MESSTECHNIK(02), CCE(03)\line   Var  On BLUERAYDRIVE(04), HU(05), FU(06), TUNERBOX(07), SOUND(08), SOUND2(09), PASS(10), KOMBI(11), DISPLAYS(12)\line    \'a6   \'a6 \line    \'a6   +- electrical wakeup line\line    +----- Voltage source\line\line\line\par
}
```

Comment: "The lines of text are irrelevant to this question i think" They're definitely relevant. Could you post a small sample of complete richtext that replicates the problem for you?

Comment: @Equalsk I added the complete rtf to reproduce my problem. Hope it helps you. Thanks for your time

Comment: How are you creating this richtext in the first place? Is it loaded in from a file? The problem is with the markup as you described. The issue is the `/v` tag being in the wrong place. Once I correct this as per your second example everything works absolutely fine and I can no longer create the problem.